# rails polymorphic association naming suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a container class I need to name, today it is called "EnrollmentApplication". It is a container of one type of application.

I've decided to push some of the business logic specific to different types of applications into a delegate associated with the application via a polymorphic relationship, to allow support for different types of applications. I'm struggling with a good name for the class and the relationship:

today:
EnrollmentApplication and applicationable

It's no longer just an application, but a collection of tasks and steps , kind of a workflow.

Portfolio and portfoliable....

ApplicationContainer and containable....

thanks
Joel

Comment: Maybe just me but I would not use the name application as it is probably reserved in Rails it `applicatin_controller`, `application.rb` `Rails.application` etc....

Comment: More info and what your trying to do would help other wise all we got for classes is `application` but that is probably a bad name to use anyways.

Comment: ok good call today its called "EnrollmentApplication, but I was trying to make it more generic

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your class is called Enrollment then the following could work:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrollment_applications
    has_many :enrollments, :through => :enrollment_applications
end
```

Then you need your join table:

```
class EnrollmentApplication < Active Record::Base 
   belongs_to :enrollment
end
```

I really don't know if this will work because rails might complain about only having one id. I'm gonna try this when I get home to see if you can do this because I am actually setting up and app where user has many users. Anyway, keep us posted on your progress.